# How to prove the convergence or non-convergence of $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n^{13}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My problem is to prove that the following series is convergent or non-convergent:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n^{13}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1},\;\;\;\;\;n=\pm 1, 2, 3, ...$$

Any hints how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: divide top and bottom by $n^{13}$ and compare to some sequence you know well.

Comment: If you can solve the problem now, then write it up and post it as an answer to your question. Then, later, you can accept your answer. This helps to keep the Unanswered Questions list in check.

Comment: It also helps others who didn't get the hint :)

Comment: +1 I will do that when and if I get it solved =) thank you

Comment: Hi @GerryMyerson what do you think about my answer?...I think I got $\infty-\infty$ as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also apply directly the comparison test: $$\frac{n^{13}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1}\ge\frac{n^{13}}{4n^{13.2}}=\frac14\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$$ and the p-test tells us the series diverges.

Comment: Hi @Timbuc shouldn't the inequality be other way around?

Comment: @jjepsuomi, you are right. Correcting.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $n^{13.2}$ is the real root of the equation $X^5=n^{66}$, you can divide numerator and denominator by $n^{13}$ and compare the series with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

So my task was to show whether

$$\displaystyle \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n^{13}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1},\;\;\;\;\;n=\pm 1, 2, 3, ...$$

converges or not. I do what was hinted (divide by $n^{13}$):

$$\displaystyle \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/5}+\frac{2n^6-1}{n^{13}}}$$

Now I calculated few of the values of the series:

$$\cdots+\frac{1}{(-2)^{1/5}+\frac{2(-2)^6-1}{(-2)^{13}}}+\frac{1}{(-1)^{1/5}+\frac{2(-1)^6-1}{(-1)^{13}}}+\frac{1}{1^{1/5}+\frac{2(1)^6-1}{(1)^{13}}}+\frac{1}{2^{1/5}+\frac{2(2)^6-1}{(2)^{13}}}+\cdots$$

I notice that when $n<0$ the denominator is always negative and hence the whole term is negative (being the opposite of the case, when $n>0$), so I can write it equivalently as:

$$\cdots-\frac{1}{2^{1/5}+\frac{2(2)^6-1}{(2)^{13}}}-\frac{1}{1^{1/5}+\frac{2(1)^6-1}{(1)^{13}}}+\frac{1}{1^{1/5}+\frac{2(1)^6-1}{(1)^{13}}}+\frac{1}{2^{1/5}+\frac{2(2)^6-1}{(2)^{13}}}+\cdots $$

Or I can write it as:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/5}+\frac{2n^6-1}{n^{13}}}-\frac{1}{n^{1/5}+\frac{2n^6-1}{n^{13}}}\right)= 0$$

So the series vanishes. Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this true?... :)

Comment: I guess I got it wrong...can someone explain why? :)

Comment: It is wrong since the sum of an infinite series of positive terms cannot vanish, @jjepsuomi. Besides, the above would imply the series converges, but it in fact diverges.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your comment @Timbuc :) Was my algebra correct by the way? :) Was there any mistake besides the end.